# FSM state machine in Verilog

Tags: initialization, verilog, fsm

If there is no reset in the input, how do you set the initial state to state_0 ?

```
reg[2:0]    state;


localparam  s0 = 3'b000, s1 = 3'b001, s2 = 3'b010, s3 = 3'b011, s4 = 
3'b100, s5 = 3'b101;    
assign  state = s0; /* NOT SURE IF THIS IS RIGHT!*/


localparam  i=0, j=64, k=0, h=0; 


always @ ( posedge clk ) begin

case( state )

        s0: ........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that will not work, because an `assign` statement will force `state = s0` all the time. The compiler will also complain about multiple drivers setting `state`. If there is no reset signal, one option is:

```
initial begin
  // set any initial values
  state = s0;
end
```

This would go in place of where you have the `assign` statement. This works well in simulation, but an even better practice would be to modify your state logic:

```
localparam  s0 = 3'b000, s1 = 3'b001, s2 = 3'b010, s3 = 3'b011, s4 = 3'b100, s5 = 3'b101;
reg [2:0] state, next_state;

always @(posedge clk) begin
  state <= next_state;
end

always @(state) begin
  case (state)
  // modify this state logic to reflect your FSM
  s0: next_state <= s1;
  s1: next_state <= s2;
  s2: next_state <= s3;
  s3: next_state <= s4;
  s4: next_state <= s5;
  s5: next_state <= s0;
  // this controls the behavior at bringup w/o a reset
  // you should include a default case even with a reset
  default: next_state <= s0;
  endcase
end

always @(state) begin
  case (state)
  // modify this output logic to reflect your FSM
  s0: // set your output signals accordingly
  s1: // set your output signals accordingly
  s2: // set your output signals accordingly
  s3: // set your output signals accordingly
  s4: // set your output signals accordingly
  s5: // set your output signals accordingly
  // this controls the behavior at bringup w/o a reset
  // you should include a default case even with a reset
  default: // set all outputs to 0
  endcase
end
```

The separation of the logic into the clocked `always` block and the combinational state transition logic above helps to create a latch-free design. I know it's more than what you asked, but this coding style helps create good synthesized designs.

Comment: thank you! I can't seem to upvote your answer since I'm new, but I would give it one.

Comment: Why is your 2nd always block "always @(state)" ? Shouldn't it just be "always @(posedge clk) begin" ?

Comment: @beepboopbeepboop Since you asked the question instead of upvoting, you can accept the answer.

Comment: I'll point out that using a default case is the way to go since that should send the X state at startup to s0. However, in the real world you are going to start up in some random state and this state may be a valid one. In that case your FSM will start operating immediately from that state and you could get different startup behavior every time. Short answer: you really want a reset if possible.

Comment: Completely agree with @nguthrie. Also to answer your question @beepboopbeepboop, an `always` block doesn't only need to trigger on `posedge clk`. An `always` block runs the logic inside it whenever the value of a signal in the sensitivity list (the `@(...)` part) changes. When you have a `always @(posedge clk)` block it creates a sequential logic block. When you have a `always @(// other signals)` it creates a combination logic block. This method of writing logic is generally referred to as behavioral design methodology. Usually it is the most readable (especially in the case of FSMs).

Comment: Also: I am not an FPGA user, but I believe that `initial` will work if your synthesis target is an FPGA.